# How can I tell how big a minipage is?

Tags: boxes, minipage, debugging

I'm debugging a document layout that uses a minipage, and I've seen somewhere where you can turn on an option to draw rectangles around the various boxes for debugging. However, I tried searching and can't figure out what option this is.

Is there an option to draw debug boxes around items (e.g. minipage)? If so, how do I configure it?

Comment: `\fbox{< some box >}` ?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#framebox_and_fbox

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26827/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208806/197451